# Wordpress - get attachment images that are currently used in a post

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment

I know that there are plenty of questions similar to this one. But the thing is that if we use `get_attached_media` function, we get **all** attachments that were added to this post through all its revisions. I only need those image attachments that are **currently** included and used in post content.

Currently to achieve this task I parse post for `<img>` tags. Is there more performance-friendly / elegant approach?

Comment: You could also use `get_attached_media` and then check which URL's appear in the post body. Maybe with `strpos`? Should be faster than DOM parsing / RegExp.